# Self join on amount field not working in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

With below data i am trying to get employees of same location and department with type as manager whose salary is equals to sum of other employees sal

```
EMP_Name    EMP_Loc EMP_Dept    EMP_Sal Emp_type
Arjun       Hyd     Comp        1000    Manager
Ramesh      Hyd     Comp        500     Interim
Ragav       Hyd     Comp        300     Interim
Rajesh      Hyd     Comp        200     Interim
```

I have tried this way and returning records correctly  but is it correct way of do it if there is huge data?

```
select  a.emp_dept , a.emp_loc ,a.emp_dept,b.emp_dept
     from  
     (select sum(emp_sal) as sett,emp_loc,emp_dept
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Interim'
                   group by emp_loc,emp_dept
                  ) a
                  inner join 
                  (select emp_sal ,emp_loc,emp_dept
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Manager'
                  ) b 
     on a.sett=b.emp_sal and a.emp_loc=b.emp_loc and a.emp_dept=b.emp_dept;
```

Comment: [There's nothing wrong with your query.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e745cc13bf9979c4284aea77c0529f6b)

Comment: its not working

Comment: Clearly you can see from the link above that it does work. Suggest you create a Fiddle that demonstrates your issue, otherwise there is nothing to answer.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: no errors first query simply not returning data and second query returning data but is it correct of way do it?

Comment: @Stu i have edited my question , please check now ,not sure why vote down on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With below data i am trying to get employees of same location and department with type as manager whose salary is equals to sum of other employees sal

You need a correlation clause:

```
select * 
from employee e
where e.emp_sal = (select sum(e2.emp_sal) 
                   from employee e2
                   where e2.emp_type = 'Interim' and
                         e2.EMP_Loc = e.EMP_Loc and
                         e2.EMP_Dept = e.EMP_Dept
                  ) and
      e.emp_type = 'Manager';
```

For performance, you want an index on `(emp_loc, emp_dept, empt_type, salary)`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon!  how to select e2 data emp_name ,if there are millions of records is it correct way of do it?

Comment: I have tried this way select  a.emp_dept , a.emp_loc ,a.emp_dept,b.emp_dept
     from  
     (select sum(emp_sal) as sett,emp_loc,emp_dept
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Interim'
                   group by emp_loc,emp_dept
                  ) a
                  inner join 
                  (select emp_sal ,emp_loc,emp_dept
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Manager'
                  ) b 
     on a.sett=b.emp_sal and a.emp_loc=b.emp_loc and a.emp_dept=b.emp_dept;

Comment: @user914357 . . . With the right index, this version should be fine.

Comment: hi Gordon , coming back to your answer , how to retrieve e2 details in select statement from your answer?

Comment: @user914357 . . . I believe this answers the question that you asked here.  If you have a new question, you should ask it as a *new* question rather than as a comment.

Comment: Hi , it answers the question i just want to know how to get details of emp2 details rather than raising duplicate question.

Comment: i have posted new question as per your advice https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68593807/how-to-access-columns-from-correlated-subquery

Comment: i have updated my question with joins please check and help