# How to access columns from correlated subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

With below data i am trying to get employees of same location and department with type as manager whose salary is equals to sum of other employees sal along with emp ids as empids are unequal query not returning any result also grouping query should have more than 1 record
so result should not include Raghu record and also i want emp ids of all the records that are matched :

```
  EMP_ID  EMP_Name    EMP_Loc EMP_Dept    EMP_Sal Emp_type
     1      Arjun       Hyd     Comp        1000    Manager
     2      Ramesh      Hyd     Comp        500     Interim
     3     Ragav       Hyd     Comp        300     Interim
     4     Rajesh      Hyd     Comp        200     Interim
     5     Raghu       Hyd     Comp        1000    Interim




 select  a.emp_dept , a.emp_loc ,a.emp_dept,b.emp_dept,a.emp_id,b.emp_id
     from  
     (select sum(emp_sal) as sett,emp_loc,emp_dept,emp_id
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Interim'
                   group by emp_loc,emp_dept,emp_id having count(emp_sal)>1
                  ) a
                  inner join 
                  (select emp_sal ,emp_loc,emp_dept,emp_id
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Manager'
                  ) b 
     on a.sett=b.emp_sal and a.emp_loc=b.emp_loc and a.emp_dept=b.emp_dept;
```

Comment: If you want columns from a table, then use a `join` of some sort.

Comment: What is your desired result?

Comment: updated my question and query , i know where is the problem because emp id is not equal and also having clause it doesnt return any data, but my sum query should have more than 1 record , i am trying to demonstrate one to many example

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  Any help here much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are including the emp_id in your first sub-select and grouping on it.  This means that you get three rows, and the sum becomes pointless.  There is never a case where the manager has 500, 200 or 300 salary, so the join doesn't work and there are therefore no records returned.  If you do this instead it should work:

```
select  a.emp_dept, a.emp_loc, b.emp_id
     from  
     (select sum(emp_sal) as sett,emp_loc,emp_dept
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Interim' and emp_sal > 1
                   group by emp_loc,emp_dept
                  ) a
                  inner join 
                  (select emp_sal ,emp_loc,emp_dept,emp_id
                   from employee 
                   where emp_type = 'Manager'
                  ) b 
     on a.sett=b.emp_sal and a.emp_loc=b.emp_loc and a.emp_dept=b.emp_dept;
```

Note that I also removed duplicate columns in the resultset.  There is no point showing b.emp_dept as well as a.emp_dept, because the join condition guarantees that they will be the same.

EDIT

Following your revision to the question, I understand now what you are trying to do.  This is really difficult to achieve, since what you need to do, is to take a cartesian sum of all the possible Interim salaries for a location and department to check if any possible combination of salary sums matches that of the Manager.

One possible way to do this would be the following:

```
WITH cte as
(SELECT a.emp_id as aempid, b.emp_id as bempid, 0 as cempid, 0 as dempid, a.emp_sal + b.emp_sal AS SumSal, a.emp_loc, a.emp_dept
FROM employee a
CROSS JOIN employee b WHERE a.emp_loc = b.emp_loc AND a.emp_dept = b.emp_dept
AND a.emp_type = b.emp_type AND a.emp_type = 'Interim' AND a.emp_id <> b.emp_id
AND b.emp_id > a.emp_id
UNION
SELECT a.emp_id, b.emp_id, c.emp_id, 0, a.emp_sal + b.emp_sal + c.emp_sal  AS SumSal, a.emp_loc, a.emp_dept
FROM employee a
CROSS JOIN employee b 
CROSS JOIN employee c
WHERE a.emp_loc = b.emp_loc AND a.emp_dept = b.emp_dept
AND a.emp_type = b.emp_type AND a.emp_type = 'Interim' AND a.emp_id <> b.emp_id
AND a.emp_loc = c.emp_loc AND a.emp_dept = c.emp_dept
AND a.emp_type = c.emp_type AND a.emp_id <> c.emp_id AND b.emp_id <> c.emp_id
AND b.emp_id > a.emp_id AND c.emp_id > b.emp_id
UNION
SELECT a.emp_id, b.emp_id, c.emp_id, d.emp_id, a.emp_sal + b.emp_sal + c.emp_sal + d.emp_sal AS SumSal, a.emp_loc, a.emp_dept
FROM employee a
CROSS JOIN employee b 
CROSS JOIN employee c
CROSS JOIN employee d
WHERE a.emp_loc = b.emp_loc AND a.emp_dept = b.emp_dept
AND a.emp_type = b.emp_type AND a.emp_type = 'Interim' AND a.emp_id <> b.emp_id
AND a.emp_loc = c.emp_loc AND a.emp_dept = c.emp_dept
AND a.emp_type = c.emp_type AND a.emp_id <> c.emp_id AND b.emp_id <> c.emp_id
AND a.emp_loc = d.emp_loc AND a.emp_dept = d.emp_dept
AND a.emp_type = d.emp_type AND a.emp_id <> d.emp_id AND b.emp_id <> d.emp_id AND c.emp_id <> d.emp_id
AND b.emp_id > a.emp_id AND c.emp_id > b.emp_id AND d.emp_id > c.emp_id
)
SELECT m.emp_id as managerid, cte.aempid, cte.bempid, cte.cempid, cte.dempid, m.emp_sal, m.emp_loc, m.emp_dept
FROM employee m 
INNER JOIN cte ON cte.emp_loc = m.emp_loc AND cte.emp_dept = m.emp_dept AND m.emp_sal = cte.sumsal
WHERE m.emp_type = 'Manager';
```

This is really ugly, but I could think of nothing better, and at least it returns the desired result.  In practice of course, you would have to create it dynamically to match the maximum number of Interim employees in any one location/department.

A couple of points in case it is not clear.  With this approach there is no need for a `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` since the requirement a.emp_id <> b.emp_id etc. guarantees that there are at least two different Interim employees.  Also the requirement that b.emp_id > a.emp_id (and c and d) is there to ensure that each possible combination of a, b, c and d only occurs once (so in this case we get just 2, 3, 4 (in that order) plus 0 for d, not all possible combinations of 2, 3, and 4.

Comment: this wont work if you include emp_id and also please keep grouping query having (emp_sal)>1 ,grouping query should have more than 1 record.

Comment: But if you put emp_id back in, the sum doesn't work. What you can do is have another subquery to get the sum right and then join on emp_loc and emp_dept to get the multiple rows or use a running sum instead. Having emp_sal > 1 doesn't do what you want. You need to do count(*) > 1

Comment: by mistake now updated my question with having count(emp_sal)>1 , i think both having count(*) >1 and having count(emp_sal) >1 are  same , if you know the answer can you please post ,it will help lot of people

Answer (score 0):

**Sample data**

[image]

**solution:**

```
SELECT a.EMP_ID, a.EMP_Name, a.EMP_Loc, a.EMP_Dept, a.EMP_Sal, a.Emp_type
FROM   employee AS a INNER JOIN
                         (SELECT SUM(EMP_Sal) AS sal, EMP_Loc,EMP_Dept
                           FROM  employee AS employee_1
                           WHERE (Emp_type = 'Interim')
                           GROUP BY EMP_Loc, EMP_Dept having Count(EMP_Sal)>1) AS b 
ON a.EMP_Dept = b.EMP_Dept AND a.EMP_Loc = b.EMP_Loc AND a.EMP_Sal = b.sal 
WHERE a.Emp_type= 'Manager'
```

**Results:**

[image]

Comment: this wont work if you include emp_id and also please keep grouping query having (emp_sal)>1 ,grouping query should have more than 1 record to sum.

Comment: @user914357 updated!! please upvote and mark if worked. this will help the others.

Comment: i dont see condition  having count(emp_sal)>1 and also dont see emp id in select clause of both outer and group query

Comment: @user914357 Updated!!

Comment: my query also works same way with out emp_id from b , see your query updated  SELECT a.EMP_ID, a.EMP_Name, a.EMP_Loc, a.EMP_Dept, a.EMP_Sal, a.Emp_type,b.emp_id
FROM   employee AS a INNER JOIN
                         (SELECT SUM(EMP_Sal) AS sal, EMP_Loc,EMP_Dept,emp_id
                           FROM  employee AS employee_1
                           WHERE (Emp_type = 'Interim')
                           GROUP BY EMP_Loc, EMP_Dept,emp_id having Count(EMP_Sal)>1) AS b 
on a.EMP_Dept = b.EMP_Dept AND a.EMP_Loc = b.EMP_Loc AND a.EMP_Sal = b.sal 
WHERE a.Emp_type= 'Manager'

Comment: @user914357 What is the desired result you are looking for?

Comment: Same result but i want to access b.emp_id and a.emp_id

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for all groups of employees that have a total salary that equals their manager's salary. In order to find all these groups you need a recursive query in SQL. In PostgreSQL you can use an array to collect the employees in  that query.

### Sample data:

| emp_id | emp_type | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Manager | 1000 |
| 2 | Interim | 500 |
| 3 | Interim | 500 |
| 4 | Interim | 300 |
| 5 | Interim | 200 |

### Result:

| manager_id | employee_ids |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {2,3} |
| 1 | {2,4,5} |
| 1 | {3,4,5} |

### The query:

```
with recursive cte(manager_id, manager_salary, employee_ids, total, loc, dept) as
(
  select emp_id, emp_sal, array[]::integer[], 0, emp_loc, emp_dept
  from employee 
  where emp_type = 'Manager'
  union
  select cte.manager_id, cte.manager_salary, cte.employee_ids || e.emp_id,
         cte.total + e.emp_sal, cte.loc, cte.dept
  from cte
  join employee e 
         on e.emp_loc = cte.loc
         and e.emp_dept = cte.dept
         and e.emp_type <> 'Manager'
         and e.emp_id > all(cte.employee_ids) 
         and cte.total + e.emp_sal <= cte.manager_salary
)
select manager_id, manager_salary, employee_ids
from cte
where total = manager_salary
and array_length(employee_ids, 1) > 1
order by manager_id, employee_ids;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=5311cdaebdc875440d9e226ace8dfefc

### As a bonus:

At last the query with the employee IDs unnested, so you see the groups in multiple line with one line per employee:

```
with recursive cte(manager_id, manager_salary, employee_ids, total, loc, dept) as
(
  select emp_id, emp_sal, array[]::integer[], 0, emp_loc, emp_dept
  from employee 
  where emp_type = 'Manager'
  union
  select cte.manager_id, cte.manager_salary, cte.employee_ids || e.emp_id,
         cte.total + e.emp_sal, cte.loc, cte.dept
  from cte
  join employee e 
         on e.emp_loc = cte.loc
         and e.emp_dept = cte.dept
         and e.emp_type <> 'Manager'
         and e.emp_id > all(cte.employee_ids) 
         and cte.total + e.emp_sal <= cte.manager_salary
)
select cte.manager_id, cte.manager_salary,
  dense_rank() over (partition by cte.manager_id order by cte.employee_ids) as grp,
  e.*
from cte
cross join lateral unnest(employee_ids) link(employee_id)
join employee e on e.emp_id = link.employee_id
where cte.total = cte.manager_salary
and array_length(cte.employee_ids, 1) > 1
order by cte.manager_id, grp, e.emp_id;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7b6218f28cbf1e9d4c1a0c76c46b9601